# Can't find LineString or Point for Python

Tags: python, point, linestring

I am trying to use PolyLabel. I did a pip install shapely first. But the

```
 from shapely import LineString
```

fails to find LineString.

Also, in polylabel there is an

```
 from ..geometry import Point
```

which can not find ..geometry.

Where can I find the ..geometry library to pip in?

Why can't Linestring be found in shapely?

Comment: Have you tried:
from shapely.geometry import LineString

Comment: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#linestrings

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that resolved the issue.

The polylabel Python program at Github, showed an example use of polylabel as

```
from shapely import LineString
polygon = LineString([(0, 0), (50, 200), (100, 100), (20, 50),
  ... (-100, -20), (-150, -200)]).buffer(100)
```

But the following fails:

```
from shapely import LineString
```

But it needed to be

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
```

Now the polylabel code itself contained

```
from ..geometry import Point
```

and this needed to be changed to:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
```